# How to set Uilabel text to nil +iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have dynamic UIButtons with subview is UIlabel.
My requirement is to display one label text in one button first time, after based on user selection(long press on the button) need to update the particular button subview label text and remove rest of the button subview label text.

I tried in this way

```
for (int i=0; i < [arr count]; i++) 
{
          UILabel *myLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 70, 60, 21)];
        if (myissue.tag ==1) {
            myLbl.text = @"Default";
        }else {
            myLbl.text = @"";
        }
        myLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        myLbl.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0/255.0 green:51.0/255.0 blue:51.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        [myLbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
        myLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        myLbl.tag = i+1;
        [myButton addSubview:defaultLbl];
        [myLbl release];
}

And for retrieving the UILabel text 
- (void)longPressTap:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
if ([recognizer.view tag]) {
   for (UIButton *btn in scrollView.subviews) {
                UIButton *btnTag = (UIButton *)btn;
                 NSLog(@"--sv:%@", btn.subviews);
                 if (recognizer.view.tag == btnTag.tag){
                      [[btn.subviews objectAtIndex:3] text] ;
                    }else {

                        [[btn.subviews objectAtIndex:3] textAttributesForNil] ;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

my problem is i was not able to selected button subview label text and removing rest of the button label text.
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnt need to add a label as a subview for a button, buttons already have their own text label that can be set using `[button setTitle:(NSString *) forState:(UIControlState)]`

and to remove the text just set `seTitle:@""`

Comment: ah, it sounded like there would be only one label at a time